# Xamarin Deployment Fails Without Any Error

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin

So I was playing with Xamarin for 2 weeks. I was able to build and run the project on my Android device.

Today I tried the release mode and built an APK and signed it. Everything was fine until that. After I built and installed the APK to my Android device, deployment started to fail. It builds successfully but it can't deploy it on my Android device. It's worth noting that I chose the debug mode.

The funny thing is, it deploys to a virtual device but not to my physical device. I tried cleaning and rebuilding the project and it did not fix the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uninstall any previously deployed .apk from your phone , that could potentially be signed with a different keystore and then try to build again

Comment: Thanks it worked. I thought i allready uninstalled the app but i was wrong.